# Is it possible to plot a cartesian coordinate system with ggvis?

Tags: r, ggvis

the topic says it all. Just want to know/figure out how I can plot an interactive cartesian coordinate system (the origin of both axes is in the center) with ggvis.

Is that possible? Google didnt help...
Here is a short example:

```
library(ggvis)
library(magrittr)

x = -5:5
y = -5:5
data = data.frame("x"=x,"y"=y)
plot = data %>% ggvis(~x,~y) 
plot
```

EDIT:
Ok, I figured something out:

```
plot = data %>% ggvis(~x,~y) %>% add_axis("x",offset=-250, grid=NA) %>% add_axis("y",offset=-250,grid=NA)
```

With the property offset I can "offset" the axis. But they are not fixed. If I resize the viewer window, they move of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution (a bit of a hack) is to draw the lines using `layer_paths()`

```
data_line <- data.frame(
  x_rng = c(-5, 5), 
  y_rng = c(0, 0)
)  

data_line2 <- data.frame(
  x_rng = c(0, 0), 
  y_rng = c(-5, 5)
)  

data %>% ggvis(~x, ~y) %>%
  layer_paths(
    x = ~x_rng, 
    y = ~y_rng,
    stroke := "black", 
    data = data_line
  ) %>%
  layer_paths(
    x = ~x_rng, 
    y = ~y_rng,
    stroke := "black", 
    data = data_line2
  ) %>%
  layer_points()
```